# Can't install Windows 7 on SSD drive

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-installation

I am trying to install Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit on an OCZ SSD Agility 3 60GB, and the drive isn't recognized in the disk management utility of Windows instalation.

I just bought an Intel Motherboard DH67CL, and an Intel Core i3 processor. My BIOS was just updated...

If i run Windows on a normal HDD, it recognizes my SSD drive, no problem. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using an SP0 or SP1 disc?

Comment: windows? Service Pack 1

Comment: Any DVD driver needed? Try to change BIOS boot order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-installer-will-not-recognize-ssd/80a83aed-56dc-438c-a65e-a0ea815ce551) seems to be about a similar issue so it might be worth a look. It describes an issue with installing Windows onto a disk with an invalid MBR/boot sector where Windows won't install.

This is the suggested resolution:

> 1. Boot up Windows 7 disc.
> 2. When the welcome screen comes up on Windows Setup, press
>      <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, which will display a command
>      prompt.
> 3. Type `diskpart` and press enter.
> 4. Type `list disk` and press enter.
> 5. Hopefully you can see your SSD in the list. You should see a number
>      identifying it. Now type `select disk X` (where `X` is the number
>      identifying your SSD) and press enter.
> 6. Type `clean` and press enter. This will write a blank MBR, **YOU WILL
>      LOSE ANY DATA ON THE SSD** if you did have anything on it.

Comment: The linked answer is exactly what I needed for my SSD. For the record, I also installed Window 7 on a SSD with an already existing install on a hard drive. It would not see my SSD, so I booted into the hard drive, then partitioned/formatted the SSD as a single partition. Once I did this, everything worked fine for the install.

Comment: That's what we like to hear, I have to admit it's not something I would have expected to be a problem any more than an unformatted hard drive.

Comment: IMHO; Win 7 Setup should see the SSD, it's no matter SSD is formatted or not. If not, Setup can create partition & format as you want. But first it should recognize the disk.

Comment: It certainly seems weird

Comment: This did not help for me, win7 setup was still in bad mood. What helped me however is to cancel out to the opening screen (with the "Install now" button), re-plug the USB stick into !!A DIFFERENT!! USB port and tadaaa, MAGIC.

Comment: The recipe helped me, but only once I *restarted* my PC after cleaning the disk as described.

Answer (score 0):

I updated firmware for [intel ssd disk](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=18363) by maiking bootable flash with firmware iso. It takes 30 seconds. Then windows was successfully installed on ssd disk.

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect all your other drives. It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. If you're able, please consider adding some additional explanation as to why this works. Thanks for contributing.