# Crucial BX100 SSD installation in an Asus Q550LF

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd

I just purchased a [Crucial BX100](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/storage-ssd-bx100) SSD to install in my [Asus Q550LF](http://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q550LF). The system BIOS is at version 211. I made sure that the drive was  [compatible](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/q550lf/CT6574749) with my machine prior to the purchase. I installed the new SSD, I can see the SSD in BIOS, but when I try to install Windows 8.1 (via DVD), it says that the system cannot find a drive to install to. It then prompts me to install drivers of some sort.

My next step right now is to connect it to a SATA to USB cable to see if I can make in progress there, but any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated.

Am I doing anything incorrectly?

UPDATE:

I went to the article that was marked as a duplicate, the solution did not work. I see no disk when I go to list my disk. My situation is different, making this question a 'non - duplicate' question.

I reached out to Crucials customer service, they don't have any idea either as to why it's not working.

I will be flashing my BIOS to see if that lets me see my drive. If not, I'll be returning the drive.

FINAL UPDATE:

It ended up being that my BIOS needed to be flashed. I flashed it to 215. The installation would NOT let me use a GPT partition on the SSD. I followed [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/325400/cant-install-windows-7-on-ssd-drive) to partition the SSD to MBR. I am unsure as how to mark my own question as an answer, maybe I can't since I don't have enough rep.

Comment: post an answer. Wait I think a day or two. Select is as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

To install Windows 8.1, the SSD has to be a GPT disk. Check in disk management whether that is the case or whether it is a MBR disk like in my example. If not, convert it to GPT (also in disk management - right click on the same place).

[image]

Comment: Alright, I did this, but I am getting the same results :(

Comment: So the SSD is GPT now - right.

Comment: Yes it is. I have also tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 as well, and Ubuntu won't see the SSD either. I'm wondering if this is a BIOS issue.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu may not  see a GPT disk (not sure though). I would define a primary active partition on the SSD and try to install 8.1 into that.

Comment: Windows didn't end up liking the GPT partition, moved it back to MBR. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: That is strange, W8.1 installs on a GPT disk. You must have another problem.

Comment: I did an update to my BIOS, which fixed it allowed me to actually see the SSD. I was surpised as well when it wouldn't let me install 8.1 to GPT disk.